# Android - How to exit application only when home page is reached?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main activity that hosts a lot of fragments and a "home page" fragment. Every time I want to add a fragment, I will call this method inside the main activity.

```
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "new_fragment");
        ft.addToBackStack("new_fragment").commit();
    }
```

Whenever the user presses the back button of the phone, I want the "home page" fragment to be the last page the user sees before he exits the application. How can I do that? I have tried this inside the onBackPressed() inside the MainActivity but it doesn't work (the back button is not working).

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("new_fragment");

        //if fragment is home page fragment, exit application
        //else pop the newest fragment or go to home page fragment
        if (fragment == fragDefault) { 
            finish(); 
        } else {
            if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
                //display home page fragment here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your back stack when you press the back button/key.

1. When adding your 'home page' Fragment, don't put it to the back stack.
2. Add all other Fragments when needed and put them to the back stack.
3. When user press the back button/key, if the back stack is empty, exit app, else pop up Fragment from back stack.

```
int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
if (count == 0) {
    finish();
}
else {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you might want to try this:

```
if (f instanceof HomePageFragmentClass) {
    finish();
} else {
    //f.dosomething();
}
```

*I have not tested it yet, let me know if it works.